# MySQL files have been deleted all of a sudden

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, data-recovery, data-loss

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 instance running the LAMP stack. Everything was working fine. Yesterday all of a sudden, the server started denying access to login via root. After a couple of trials, I gained access to the system. To my realisation, `dpkg` directory had some issues which I fixed by manually making folders. Still the application did not start. Upon further investigation, I noticed that

> MySQL - Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

was being displayed on the application home page. Going further, I found out that the entire MySQL data along with the logs had disappeared. I don't know what is wrong!! Kindly help with solutions.

Comment: Your MySQL data lives in `/var/lib/mysql`, not in `/var/run/`, if that helps.

Comment: I had around 100 tables which is nowhere to be found in `/var/lib/mysql`. `/var/run` contained the socket related issue.

Comment: MySQL files are writable only by the `mysql` user. So if they have been deleted, it must have been by a root-level process. Stop the MySQL server, restore your data from backup, and restart the server.

Comment: In the `/var/lib/mysql` folder, I can see ibdata1, ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1. How do I use that to recover data? Also do you know what is the cause of such issues?

Comment: Those *are* your data files. The tables are inside them, unless you have somehow reinitialized the server. Restart the server and do `show databases` etc.

Comment: When I type in `mysql` I get `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)`

Comment: Then your server is not running. Check `sudo service mysql status` .

Comment: Boot from a live USB and check the file system integrity with `fsck -f` on the partitions of your disk devices.